# How do I modify tensor shape when loading a model checkpoint with tf.train.Saver?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained a RNN with a fixed batch size, but now I'd like to modify the graph I saved with `tf.train.Saver` to have batch size 1 for inference. How can I go about this?

```
session = tf.InteractiveSession()
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.ckpt.meta')
saver.restore(session, 'model.ckpt')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to achieve this is to reconstruct a different (albeit compatible) network at test time and limit the recovery to weights only.

During training,

```
net = make_my_net(batch_size)
...
saver.save(session, model_name)
```

During testing,

```
net = make_my_net(1)
...
saver.restore(session, model_name)
```

The later will replace the values of variables (including network weights) with the ones that were saved earlier. You don't have to initialize the variables that you are about to overwrite according to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables), although I believe it has not always been so.

Note that reconstructing a different network gives you the opportunity to build a cleaner test network, e.g. by removing layers such as dropout.